# Fill between x and baseline x position in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, fill

I'm looking for a way to use fill_between in matplotlib to shade between x1 and x2 as opposed to y1 and y2.

I have a series of log plots, with depth on the Y axis, and the measured variable on the x axis and would like to shade to the left or right, as opposed to above or below, of the plotted line.

I'm sure this should be possible with fill_between but cant make it work.

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec


gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, :])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1:, 1])

y=np.random.uniform(0,1,30)
x=np.arange(30)

ax1.set_ylabel('Plot 1')
ax1.plot(x,y)
ax1.fill_between(x,y,0.5,where=y>0.5,interpolate=True)

ax2.set_ylabel('Plot 2')
ax2.plot(y,x)
ax2.set_ylim(30,0)

plt.show()
```

I have attached an image of what this produces:
Essentially i want to plot something like plot 1 in the plot 2 position
[image]

Thankyou for any suggestions

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can use [`fill_betweenx`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx)

```
ax2.fill_betweenx(y,x, x2=0.5, where=x>0.5,interpolate=True)
```

Comment: Ahh.. i didn't know there was a fill_betweenx - Thank you

Comment: Note: fill_betweenx does not accept the interpolate keyword.

Comment: Do you know of a way to accomplish this without using fill_betweenx()? I really need the interpolate keyword, and it looks like that's not included in fill_betweenx() until matplotlib 2.1.